Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:23) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type
i tried to use emailjs in this example:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';


const ContactFormTest= () => {
  


  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
 

  const { t } = useTranslation('contactform');
 
  emailjs.init({
    publicKey: 'bb8-glF2nFNvLX5LJ',
    // Do not allow headless browsers
    blockHeadless: true,
    blockList: {
      // Block the suspended emails
      list: ['foo@emailjs.com', 'bar@emailjs.com'],
      // The variable contains the email address
      watchVariable: 'user_email',
    },
    limitRate: {
      // Set the limit rate for the application
      id: 'app',
      // Allow 1 request per 10s
      throttle: 10000,
    },
  });
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    // EmailJS Service ID, template ID and Public Key
    const serviceId = 'service_kxo6ovl';
    const templateId = 'contact_form';
    const publicKey = 'bb8-glF2nFNvLX5LJ';

  

  const templateParams = {
    user_name: name,
    user_email: email,
    message: message, 

  };
  

  emailjs.send(serviceId, templateId, templateParams)
  .then((response)=> {
    console.log('Email sent successfully!', response);
    setName('');
    setEmail('');
    setMessage('');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(serviceId, templateId, templateParams)
    console.error('Error sending email', error);
  })

}

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      name="contact-form"
      id="contact-form"
      
    >
      <div className="messages"></div>
      <div className="form-floating">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          className="form-control"
          id="name"
          required="required"
          placeholder="Your Name"
          data-error="Your Name is Required"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="name">{t('contactform.name')}</label>
        <div className="help-block with-errors mt-20"></div>
      </div>
      <div className="form-floating">
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          className="form-control"
          id="email"
          placeholder="Your Email"
          required="required"
          data-error="Please Enter Valid Email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="email">{t('contactform.email')}</label>
        <div className="help-block with-errors mt-20"></div>
      </div>
      
      <div className="form-floating">
        <textarea
          name="message"
          className="form-control"
          id="message-input-simple"
          rows="7"
          placeholder="Your Message"
          required
          data-error="Please, Leave us a message"
          value={message}
          onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        ></textarea>
        <label htmlFor="message">{t('contactform.nachricht')}</label>
        <div className="help-block with-errors mt-20"></div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" className="btn btn-color btn-circle">
      {t('contactform.button')}
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ContactFormTest;

but once I hit npm start i get following error:
./node_modules/@emailjs/browser/es/utils/isBlockedValueInParams/isBlockedValueInParams.js 3:23
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:23)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import { validateBlockListParams } from '../validateBlockListParams/validateBlockListParams';
| var isBlockListDisabled = function isBlockListDisabled(options) {
>   return !options.list?.length || !options.watchVariable;
| };
| var getValue = function getValue(data, name) {

I tried it now with the example from emailjs and i get the same error. Every help is highly appreciated. The failure code looks bit different then the one in my node modules but expect that its still the same.
Node Version v20.11.1

it runs well with vite(latest version), node v-22, react v-18
It looks like you might have specified an old version of Node.js in your configurations somewhere
{
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.0.0"
  }
}

, or you haven't installed the necessary Babel modules
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}

. If you set up Babel and Webpack yourself, you should check those configurations.
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  // Other configuration settings...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};


Thanks so much and sorry for the delay in answer. I upgraded the project with the latest dependencys and now its working.
